# Codeblocks and boost on Windows 7

Tags: boost, window, codeblocks

Attempting to set up CodeBlocks and boost on Windows 7, 64-bit.

This is what I've tried...

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef

Downloaded and Installed CodeBlocks 12.11 to C:...

```
C:\CodeBlocks
```

Downloaded boost_1_53_0.zip and unzipped to C:\boost...

```
C:\boost\boost_1_53_0
```

Checked gcc from command line...

> gcc --version
>   gcc (tdm-1) 4.7.1
>   Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

On commandline in boost folder, ran...

> bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=C:\CodeBlocks" install

Completed without error.

Explorer tree...

- C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost\accumulators\
- C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost\algorithm\
- C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost...
- C:\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_atomic-mgw47-mt-1_53.a
- C:\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_atomic-mgw47-mt-d-1_53.a
- C:\CodeBlocks\lib...

Opened CodeBlocks and set global variable...

**boost**

- base - C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost
- lib - C:\CodeBlocks\lib

Create new project - Console application

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and runs OK.

Set build options -> Search Directories...

Compiler

- $(#boost.include)

Linker

- $(#boost.lib)

Use example from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

Get this...

-------------- Clean: Debug in console_app (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "console_app - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in console_app (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp:1:35: fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

Tried the following to no avail...
    #include

-------------- Build: Debug in console_app (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp:2:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

```
#include "C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost\regex.hpp"
```

OR

```
#include "C:/CodeBlocks/include/boost-1_53/boost/regex.hpp"
```

-------------- Build: Debug in console_app (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:\dev\console_app\main.cpp:3:0:
C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53\boost\regex.hpp:28:34: fatal error: boost/regex/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

What you set your global variable $(#boost.include) to will impact on this.

Boost's own header files expect to have the compiler search directory given to them during compilation, so including boost using a direct path will not solve it.

Make sure your $(#boost.include) global variable in Code::Blocks is set to "C:\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_53"